# [bug]<paramiko.ChannelFile from <paramiko.Channel 1 (closed) ->

Tags: ssh-keys, ssh-tunnel

My requirement is to connect to some session using proxy and execute some command on that session.
I have written python code for ssh connection along with proxy connection, it's working fine. After connection we are executing the command.
When we executed the command `df` it's working fine and displaying result.
But when executed some command which is related to project `bch -c 142717 -M sim -S 2019-02-01:00:00:00` it's not working.

When we executed command mention above, it has very long output with multiple pages.
But manually when we executed the above command in session it's working fine.

```
import subprocess
import openpyxl
import os
import paramiko
import socks
import datetime
import sys
import time

#reload(sys)
#sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

ssh = ""
# sftp_client = none

host='10.64.167.69'
port=22
username='bscs1'
password='3ricss0n'
proxyHost='127.0.0.1'
proxyPort='1080'


    def CL_Open_SSHConnection_With_Proxy(host, port, username, password, proxyHost, proxyPort):

        port = int(port)
        proxyPort = int(proxyPort)
        socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, proxyHost, proxyPort, False)
        paramiko.client.socket.socket = socks.socksocket
        SERVER_ENCODING = "utf-8"
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect(hostname=host, port=port, username=username, password=password)
        chan = ssh.invoke_shell()
        chan.settimeout(0)
        print "Server Connected"
        socks.setdefaultproxy()
        print ssh
        return ssh

    def CL_execute_comand(con, sshcmd):

        print "CL_execute_comand"
        print con
        stdin, stdout, stderr = con.exec_command(sshcmd)
        print 'executed'
        print stdout
        opt = stdout.readlines()
        opt = "".join(opt)
        print(opt)

def CL_Close_Connection(ssh1):
    time.sleep(5)
    ssh1.close()

sshcmd = 'bch -c 142717 -M sim -S 2019-02-01:00:00:00'

variable = CL_Open_SSHConnection_With_Proxy(host, port, username, password, proxyHost, proxyPort)
variable2 = CL_execute_comand(variable, sshcmd)
print variable2
CL_Close_Connection(variable)
```

output:

```
<paramiko.ChannelFile from <paramiko.Channel 1 (closed) -> <paramiko.Transport at 0x2b27f28L (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (active; 0 open channel(s))>>>
```

Comment: we are not able execute customized command related to our project.But we can execute command like 'df' , ls, top -b -n1